# How to get id from generated list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
$ctr = 0;
foreach($authspons as $authspons_list){
   $ctr++;
   echo "<input type='checkbox' id='id_list'".$ctr."'"." name='authspons[]'"." class='list_check' value='".$authspons_list->authspons_position." ".$authspons_list->authspons_lname.",".$authspons_list->authspons_fname." ".$authspons_list->authspons_mname." ".$authspons_list->authspons_cmpny.'; '."'".">" .$authspons_list->authspons_position." ".$authspons_list->authspons_lname.",".$authspons_list->authspons_fname." ".$authspons_list->authspons_mname." ".$authspons_list->authspons_cmpny."</input> <br />";
  echo "<input type='text' class='text_list' id='tbox".$ctr."'"."name='authsponsid[]' value='".$authspons_list->authspons_id."; "."'"." >";
    }
```

I have a generated list coming from database, the checkboxes contains the personal details, while the textboxes contains the "ID" of each items in the checkboxes.

This is my jquery code:

```
$('#list').click(function(){
var final = '';
var final2='';
$('.list_check:checked').each(function(){        
    var values = $(this).val();
    final += values;
var val_id = $('.text_list').val();
final2 +=val_id;
});
$("#coauth").val(final);
$("#coauthid").val(final2);
$("#coauthspons").modal("hide");
});
```

Getting value from checkboxes is okay. My problem is: the output from the textbox is always the last value of the number of checkboxes that is checked.

Like this:

```
1st checkbox = 1st textbox(value="1");
2nd checkbox = 2nd textbox(value="2");
```

when i check the two options, the textbox only results to:

```
1st checkbox = 1st textbox(value="2");
2nd checkbox = 2nd textbox(value="2");
```

How do I get the result of each of the expected checkbox and its textbox value?

Comment: can you add genereated html? Where is #list exist in your code?

Comment: #list is a button that triggers the function. It exist at the modal-footer of bootstrap modal form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here `var val_id = $('.text_list').val();`

you are giving the same value for all the elements irrespective of their index

try like this

```
var val_id = $(this).next().val(); //this gives value of next i.e .text_list element
```

Comment: I've tried var val_id = $('.text_list').next().val(); but it gets the value of the checkbox not the value of the textbox

Comment: $('.text_list').next().val(); gives value of element that is next to the element having class '.text_list' i.e checkbox. but in my code it gives value of next element of checkbox. i.e '.text_list' element.Try my code and see it ll work

Comment: It returns nothing though. the class of the checkbox is "list_check" while the class of the textbox is "text_list".

Comment: can u copy the html generated and make a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#list').click(function(){
  var final = '';
var final2='';
  $('.list_check:checked').each(function(){        
    var raw_value = $(this).val();
    var id_value = raw_value.split("||");

    var values = id_value[1];
    final += values;
    var val_id = id_value[0];
    final2 +=val_id;
});
$("#coauth").val(final);
$("#coauthid").val(final2);
//alert(final2);
$("#coauthspons").modal("hide");
});
```

Thanks #Bhadra for your answer. it gives me an idea but I found a better solution to my own problem. I put all the values in the checkbox then I use split function to separate the "ID" from the original checkbox values(fname,mname,lname).